# cassandra data replication understanding

Tags: azure, cassandra, replication

I am playing with Cassandra cluster on Azure. It took me more than 1 week to get the setup done and working. Its working now but i think i misunderstood 1 concept of Cassandra i.e. how data is stored?

i was under the impression that when ever i upload the data, same data will be available across all machines i.e. if i upload 10 MB file and 4 nodes (2 seeds), all 4 will have 10MB of consumption. I guess i am wrong about this.

Because i just created 4 nodes and uploaded around (2 + 5 + 20 + 20 = 47 MB) of data (blob) but when i check the status, i see below

```
--  Address   Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.1.2.5  28.32 MB   256     47.5%             xxxxxxxx-eb9a-46fb-8213-c7487074d9a8  rc1
UN  10.1.2.4  27.14 MB      256     51.3%             xxxxxxxx-11ed-41c6-be8b-a912e54b1ccf  rc1
UN  10.1.2.7  25.09 MB   256     50.1%             xxxxxxxx-9e73-410a-b1bf-5bfd15138625  rc2
UN  10.1.2.6  23.32 MB   256     51.2%             xxxxxxxx-d132-49b6-8eda-4459391d12e4  rc2
```

BTW, replication factor for tables was "2". Load is changing slightly every couple of mins. but i can download the data and its as expected!

Sorry for being lazy and unfair, i have been googling setup for a week and would really appreciate if you could help me understand this or at least point to me to proper link.

Thanks, 
Ninad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an expected result. Each piece of your data is replicated 2 times according to your replication factor. So roughly your 47 Mb times 2 distributed across 4 nodes result in approximately 25 mb on each node.